# Matplotlib is incorrectly rendering axis labels in sans-serif when using LaTeX

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am using `matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True); matplotlib.rc('font', family='serif')` to set my font to serif with LaTeX. This works for the tick labels, however the plot title and axis lables are typeset using the sans-serif `CMS S 12` computer modern variant.

From what I have found on the web, most people seem to have trouble using the sans-serif font. For me the opposite is the case, I cannot get the serif font to work properly.

I have tried a hacky solution of setting the sans-serif font to Computer Modern, which unfortunately does not work either.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the issue together with an image of the output. Also state your version of matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was importing the `seaborn` package after setting the matplotlib rcParams, which overwrote values such as the font family. Calling `rcParams.update(params)` after importing `seaborn` fixes the problem.